# Raise error with only last line of stack trace

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, stack-trace

It seems to me that commonly you may want a Python program to print (usually to standard error) only the last line of the stack trace, e.g.:

```
IOError: Error reading file 'b'plunk'': b'failed to load external entity "plunk"'
```

I've got this solution:

```
def print_error(ex:Exception, file) -> None:
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(ex.__class__.__name__, ex), file=file)
```

Example usage:

```
try:
    crash in some manner
except Exception as ex:
    print_error(ex, sys.stderr)
```

There is nothing particularly wrong with this, but this feature seems so basic that I can't help but wonder if there isn't a simpler way to do it. Am I missing something? Or is this a good solution?

Comment: Nice to see people using function annotations. I just hope you're not static checking your code with some decorator.

Comment: @JBernardo I love annotations; I think they are exactly what Python needed—a clarification of code due to the type expected, without resignation of duck typing. No, not doing any type of static checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way of doing it, but considering that it's all of 6 lines of code and I can't imagine it takes long to carry out at all, I don't think that you need a better one.